# Transfer data from one component to another without parent and child relationship

Tags: angular

I am new in angular , I want to know is there any method or something else in angular that help me to transfer data like a variable from a component to another component without parent and child relationship (can't use input() or .... )

Comment: You can always use a service to pass data between components.  
https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services

Comment: thank you.
what if my variable generate in first component ?

Comment: you can have a shared variable in your service, that will be updated in your first component, and read in the second component.

Comment: If you are child component is a modal there is an easy way to perform it